# GWT call Axis2 on Tomcat doesn't work

Tags: gwt, tomcat, tomcat7, apache-axis, gwt-rpc

When i try to call a web service from my server java written with GWT deployed on tomcat 7 i have this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.HTTPProxyConfigurationUtil.configure(HTTPProxyConfigurationUtil.java:154)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.getHostConfiguration(AbstractHTTPSender.java:294)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:591)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.client.RPCServiceClient.invokeBlocking(RPCServiceClient.java:102)
at me.project.server.WSClient.skosClassifier(WSClient.java:103)
at me.project.server.ServerProxyImpl.getFromRemoteServer(ServerProxyImpl.java:420)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

if i deploy on another application server (like jetty), i haven't errors.
What is the problem on tomcat?

This is the code that invoke the web service:

```
static String skosClassifier(String repository,String message) throws AxisFault {
    RPCServiceClient serviceClient = new RPCServiceClient();
    Options opt = serviceClient.getOptions();
    opt.setTo(targetEPR);
    QName opEcho = new QName("http://service.project.me","skosClassifier");
    BufferedReader console=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try{
        Object[] opEchoArgs=null;
        Class[] returnTypes=new Class[]{String.class};
        Object[] response=null;
        opEchoArgs=new Object[]{repository,message,false};
        response=serviceClient.invokeBlocking(opEcho, opEchoArgs, returnTypes);
        String returnValue = (String)response[0];
        return returnValue;
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "SERVER ERROR";
```

Comment: What's on line me.project.server.WSClient.skosClassifier(WSClient.java:103)

Comment: the invocation of the web service:
RPCServiceClient.invokeBlocking(...)
The code works standalone and with others application server.

Comment: You should provide that code as you'll get a better response because of it.

Comment: i added the code in the question, but I repeat myself: the method works. i mean the problem is with tomcat, some wrong configuration or jars conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at the stack trace which shows a NumberFormatException.

Looking at the file HTTPProxyConfigurationUtil (I am checking axis2-1.6.2), that line is parsing the proxy port. Below is the relevant code .

```
String port = System.getProperty(HTTP_PROXY_PORT);
        if(port != null) {
            proxyPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
        }
```

Are you setting a valid integer value for HTTP_PROXY_PORT ? You need to check the arguments being passed in to JVM.

Comment: Where i can find this setting?

Comment: setenv.bat,senenv.sh..These are tomcat files. If your server is running on linux check setenv.sh, if its running on windows check setenv.bat..These files will contain the system properties being passed to JVM on tomcat startup. You will find these files under <<TOMCAT_HOME>>/bin

Comment: I haven't these file under <<TOMCAT_HOME>>/bin (or under others folders of tomcat)

Comment: In that case, you need to check catalina.sh,catalina.bat or startup.sh,starup.bat..You need to figure out if any value is being passed to JVM for HTTP_PROXY_PORT ..Its usually one of these files..I am assuming that you are running tomcat using one of these scripts and not from a IDE like Eclipse,Intellij

Comment: I haven't these file anywhere. I have a standalone installation of tomcat as a service on Windows.

Comment: Can you check the service properties ? The service properties will tell you what exe file it is running. It will be something like this "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\bin\tomcat6.exe". This tells you where tomcat is installed and the bin folder under tomcat which will show you the files I mentioned above.

Comment: in bin folder i have only the tomcat exes, no .bat or .sh

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the `web.xml` header is correct. Commonly the error comes through `web.xml`.

Comment: The web.xml header is auto generated by gwt plugin.
All my servlets works. And all works with others application servers.
Only that instruction throws an exception.